# Detect if homebrew package is installed

Tags: bash, shell, homebrew

I'm about to write a shell script to detect if several homebrew packages are installed in the system. Is there a way to use a brew command to achieve that?

I tried using the exit code of `brew install <formula> --dry-run`. But this builds the package if it is missing.

Comment: `brew --cellar "$formula" >/dev/null 2>&1` `--cellar formula: Display the location in the cellar where formula would be installed, without any sort of versioned directory as the last path.` [brew man page](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/manpages/brew.1.md); would have loved to give it as an answer

Comment: `if [ ! -x "$(command -v PKG_EXEC)" ]; then
  # package not installed
fi`

Answer (score 189, accepted):

You can use

```
brew ls --versions myformula
```

to output the installed versions of the respective formula. If the formula is not installed, the output will be empty.

When using a recent versions of homebrew, which you can get with `brew update`, you can just run this (thanks Slaven):

```
if brew ls --versions myformula > /dev/null; then
  # The package is installed
else
  # The package is not installed
fi
```

That said, it is probably a good idea to check for the existence of the tool at all and not just checking for the respective homebrew package (e.g. by searching for the executable in the `$PATH`). People tend to install tools in a rather large amount of ways in practice, with homebrew being just one of them.

Comment: Since https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/commit/db478fb7b2d8047403b71208af73b400bcf7a3e2 it is sufficient to check for the exit code: if the formula is not installed, then false (1) is returned.

Comment: So if I run `if macchanger --help > /dev/null; then`, will that check if `macchanger` is installed?

Comment: @KeeganKuhn If that succeeded, then `macchanger` is in the current shell's `$PATH`. If it fails, it is either not available in the PATH or not installed.

Comment: @Keegan Kuhn - If you really just want to check whether an application is on the PATH (without running it), you can use `which -s`.  The `-s` option (silent) is documented as "-s      No output, just return 0 if any of the executables are found, or 1 if none are found."  Proper usage is something like `which macchanger || echo "macchanger not on PATH"`

Comment: If you've installed some package with `--cask` option, then you can run command like `brew ls --versions adoptopenjdk11 --cask > /dev/null` by adding `--cask` at the end.

Answer (score 10):

```
# install if we haven't installed any version
brew ls --versions $lib || brew install $lib
# install if we haven't installed latest version
brew outdated $lib || brew install $lib
```

Comment: ì would go with this.

Answer (score 7):

What about?

```
for pkg in macvim ngrep other needed packages; do
    if brew list -1 | grep -q "^${pkg}\$"; then
        echo "Package '$pkg' is installed"
    else
        echo "Package '$pkg' is not installed"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Your solutions doesn't work with some versioned formula like `python@3` which is installed (and listed) as `python3`.

Answer (score 2):

For script and automation usage, I found out that `brew bundle --help` is very convenient.

If you do not want to use real bundle file, this snippet works fine in scripts:

```
brew bundle -v --file=- <<-EOF
brew "mc"
brew "ffmpeg"
brew "wget"
cask "cpuinfo"
cask "intel-power-gadget"
cask "unetbootin"
cask "vlc"
EOF
```

The good side of it, it will automatically detect if package is not installed, if it is outdated and only then will install it.

If you do not want updates, add a flag `--no-upgrade`. I have put `-v` for verbosity, as want more details, but you can skip it, or even use `-q` for even more silent run.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest two-liners:
Step one, make sure it's installed

```
$ realpath . || brew install coreutils
```

This will print out the realpath of current dir, if not, then it will install it. 
And it will not fail even realpath not found.

Step two, call it in your actual code:

```
$ realpath ${someDir}
```

Comment: This is an easy solution for a specific tool. It's not a generic solution.