# How can I implement install-or-upgrade for brew recipes?

Tags: bash, homebrew

I want to install a brew recipe or upgrade it if is already installed using bash.

The command is supposed to return a non zero exit code only if at the end the recipe is not installed.

PS. One should remark the `brew install xxx` return error code if `xxx` is already installed.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802320/detect-if-homebrew-package-is-installed

Answer (score 1):

Background: https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/30939

I just needed this also. This seems to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

package=$1
pkg_installed=false
pkg_updated=false
verbose=true

# TODO: ensure valid input

brew update >/dev/null 2>&1
list_output=`brew list | grep $package`
outdated_output=`brew outdated | grep $package`

# now enable error checking
set -e

if [[ ! -z "$list_output" ]]; then
    pkg_installed=true
    $verbose && echo "package is installed"
    if [[ -z "$outdated_output" ]]; then
        pkg_updated=true
        $verbose && echo "package is updated"
    else
        $verbose && echo "package is not updated. updating..."
        brew upgrade $package
    fi
else
    $verbose && echo "package is not installed. installing..."
    brew install $package
fi
```

Usage:

```
> brew outdated
jemalloc (4.3.0) < 4.3.1
terraform (0.7.9) < 0.7.10
> brew_install_or_upgrade.sh jemalloc; echo $?
package is installed
package is not updated. updating...
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package, with result:
jemalloc 4.3.1
==> Upgrading jemalloc
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/jemalloc-4.3.1.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring jemalloc-4.3.1.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/jemalloc/4.3.1: 16 files, 1.4M
0
> brew_install_or_upgrade.sh jemalloc; echo $?
package is installed
package is updated
0
>
```