# What does "build error: <N> (30 days)" mean when I run `brew info <package>`? Does it represent a problem with my package installation?

Tags: macos, opencv, cmake, computer-vision

I have already installed homebrew and cmake via terminal.
And After I installed opencv, and using "brew info opencv", it returns

```
install: 17,446 (30 days), 42,476 (90 days), 183,133 (365 days)
install-on-request: 17,012 (30 days), 41,116 (90 days), 177,067 (365 days)
build-error: 31 (30 days)
```

and I don't know how to solve it.

I have already searched through internet but there were no similar problems like that.

Comment: What's the problem exactly please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell  I want to use opencv with c++ or python on my Mac's vs code, and I find previous experiences that I should install homebrew and cmake first (I hope it is correct). And I successfully installed those, and I used "brew install (then reinstall) opencv". And after that I used "brew info opencv" to check if my opencv had been completely installed. and it says build-error 31. I updated my question with the whole dialogue.

Comment: As @user says, that's just a summary of other people's successes/failures. It shouldn't concern you.

Answer (score 2):

What's so problematic about this? I'm pretty sure that's just regular analytics information about what kinds of events have happened in the last `N` days, and how many times they happened. It's not (necessarily) saying that anything wrong happened with *your* installation of opencv. It would be saying that if it gave *you* particular error/warning messages *during* the installation and build process when you installed opencv on *your* machine. Seeing that you didn't show any such error messages in your question post, I'm assuming you didn't get any. So where's the fire?

You'll see the same numbers on the homebrew page for openvc: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/opencv. For posterity, I captured the page on the Internet Archive here: https://web.archive.org/web/20230221080002/https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/opencv, and you'll see pretty much the exact same numbers except slightly higher count values due to more install events happening around the world in the time between you posting your question and me posting this answer.

You can see information for the number of build errors that happened in the last 30 days for all packages here: https://formulae.brew.sh/analytics/build-error/30d/.

If you want to see information about something you installed via homebrew, see [Detect if homebrew package is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20802320/11107541), or to find out where it was installed to, use `brew --prefix [package]`.